# Box-shadow-effect for IE

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Is this the right way to do a box-shadow for IE? Does this work on your computer?

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(color='#000000',offX='20',offY='20');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-IE 9:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2, etc);
```

Post-IE8:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(attribute1=value1, attribute2=value2, etc)";
```

Comment: attribute1 would be the id for the box or div and value1 will be the color?

Comment: It should go like this example: (color=#561A0B, offX=-6, offY=-6, positive=true)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use CSS3 PIE (http://css3pie.com) rather than the DropShadow filter; the filter is very difficult to make look like CSS3 box-shadow on other browsers when you start adding blur. CSS3 PIE's box-shadow implementation is pretty much identical to other browsers, and as an added benefit it works in conjunction with border-radius (the shadow shape is rounded to match the rounded corners of the background/border.)

Answer (score 1):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ccc, Strength=10, Direction=0),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ccc, Strength=10, Direction=90),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ccc, Strength=10, Direction=180),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ccc, Strength=10, Direction=270);
```